# How to get xbox 360 wired controller in retropie to control Kodi

Tags: pi-2, wireless, kodi, retropie

Long story short I've configured my xbox360 wired controller to control my RetroPie, but I cannot get it to control Kodi. I've followed a few tutorials and no success. Any ideas or tutorials I should check?

Comment: I would give this a look: http://openelec.tv/forum/124-raspberry-pi/74287-xbox360-wireless-gamepad-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this tutorial will help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beBGRwjJI60

Follow it through and you should even have the Kodi icon added as a "Console" option

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've followed this tutorial many times and it didn't work. What I found out was that I needed the recent update of RetroPie 3.7 with Kodi 16 Jarvis,  (I couldn't find 2.6) which has game-pad support and it was just released 2 weeks ago. I was using the 3.6 version with Kodi 15.2 Isengard when it wouldn't work for anyone else who was trying this. [https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/releases/tag/3.7]